# GPIO with no pullups or pulldowns

Tags: gpio, pullup, pulldown, reliability

I have a SPDT switch connected to a GPIO pin on an nRF52810 microcontroller.
The switch has two positions:

1. Shorts the GPIO to GND
2. Shorts the GPIO to V+
   [image]

The switch is used to toggle a software feature on or off while the application is running. But, this is a battery powered application, so I am trying to minimize quiescent currents wherever possible, including eliminating pullup/pulldown resistors wherever possible.

I understand that without any pullups, there may be a brief moment where the GPIO pin's state is not define while the switch is moving between positions. But, once the switch movement has completed, we will be in a good state.

Is it bad practice to use a GPIO input with no pullups or pulldowns at all? Are there reliability issues that would make this a bad idea for longevity?

Comment: Depends. Does the MCU have a defined state during power up? If yes, then probably no issues.

Comment: It depends how often the switch is operated. If never during when MCU is running, there is no problem. But if it is switched while running, the time it spends floating is important as the MCU can read the value incorrectly at that moment, but it will end up in a stable state. So how often the switch is expected to be switched and how quickly the software must respond to it? The time the signal spends floating is bad because if it floats at logic threshold it will keep both input FETs half-on and you get excess shoot-through current from supply to ground.

Comment: Hmmm excess shoot-through current does not sound good. Would it be better if we had a pulldown resistor when tied to GND, and a pullup resistor when tied to V+? This would keep the state defined during the switch movement, then once the switch finishes moving, we re-configure the pullup/pulldown to eliminate the passive current draw. Is there a common technique to eliminate this problem?

Comment: Maybe. Does the MCU have both internal pull-ups and pull-downs?

Comment: Yes (extra words to hit minimum comment length)

Comment: the V+ connection is not really necessary

Comment: @jsotola care to elaborate?

Comment: in the circuit you presented  the input is tied directly to V+ until you operate the switch, then the input is connected to ground ... remove the direct connection between the input and V+, and replace it with a pullup resistor

Comment: If the input has a Schmitt trigger, there is no worry about shoot-through. And if the switch changes state quickly, there is probably enough capacitance on the pin to hold the previous state until the other contact closes. If in doubt, you can add a small capacitance (20-100 pF)

Comment: It's perfectly fine. For the very brief moment the switch is in between states the GPIO voltage will be held by the capacitance on the line.

Comment: @jsotola with the setup you described, there will be a constant current through the pullup resistor when the switch is connected to GND. We want to avoid this type of constant pullup resistor current as it will waste too much battery when the switch is in the grounded position.

Comment: what percentage of time is the switch connected to ground?

Comment: The switch is a do-not-disturb button, very similar to the do-not-disturb button on Apple phones. The duty cycle depends entirely on the user, but it could be anywhere from 0% to 100% duty cycle depending on when they want do-not-disturb active.

Answer (score 4):

The nRF52810 microcontroller is well-suited for the SPDT connection scheme you have come up with.

It has internal programmable pull-up and pull-down resistors on its GPIO pins, so a simple procedure can be used to get very low power position detection.

The procedure uses a 2-bit value `ps` and are:

1. Configure GPIO to pull-up.
2. Read GPIO level into `ps(1)`.
3. Configure GPIO to pull-down.
4. Read GPIO level into `ps(0)`.
5. Configure GPIO to disable pull resistors.
6. Decode `ps`: 11 is HIGH, 00 is LOW, 10 is floating (moving)

The procedure can be executed regularly, if a timer interrupt is running, or just when the higher-level program wants to. Either way, debouncing processing must be applied to the `ps` values read.

For a regular timer interrupt, this can be as simple as reading the switch slower than at, say, intervals between 5 ms and 50 ms and then only returning a new pin level when `ps` has detected the same HIGH or LOW value three times in succession.

This procedure can also detect 3 levels from a 3-position switch, such as 1-pole 3-way. That switch would connect its pole to VDD, floating or GND.

If you just connect a SPST switch from a GPIO to VDD, you can use a simpler procedure to read your two levels:

1. Configure GPIO to pull-down.
2. Read GPIO level into `ps`.
3. Configure GPIO to pull-up.
4. Use `ps`: 1 is ON, 0 is OFF.

The pull-up ensures the GPIO is not floating when not being read but the pull resistors are only 11..16 kohm so it will draw the GPIO leakage current, usually 2..6 uA max. That might be too much in a battery powered application. You could put an external 1 Mohm pull-up across the switch and make step (4) to disable pull resistors.

A downside of this SPST over your SPDT switch scheme is that a DMM or ATE cannot check the switch level in development and manufacturing. That may well not matter in your application.

Comment: Alternatively, while the switch is connceted to VDD, use a pull-up, and a pull-down while the pin is switched to ground. Toggle the resistor when servicing the switch.

Comment: @polwel, good point, though with pros and cons if, say, on a coin cell. Have expanded the answer.

Comment: I think this method will do a great job of determining the state of the switch, assuming we know ahead of time when we want to check the switch state. However, we are intending on using this switch as an asynchronous user input to toggle a software feature. We don't know when the user will toggle the switch. Our current implementation uses hardware interrupts to detect either falling or rising edges on the GPIO.

Answer (score 1):

A bus-hold circuit essentially is a pull-up/-down that connects to the last known logic level. A current flows only while switching to the other state:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQ448w.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

(You can use any buffer, or two inverters.)

Answer (score 0):

If switching is not something that happens during normal use, consider using a jumper, like this but use only three of the pins:

[image]

Connect the centre pin to your GPIO input, and the other two outer pins to V+ and Gnd, using the jumper block to join the centre pin to one of the other two. That way you don't ever leave the GPIO input floating. The circuit is equivalent to this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fJ7G2H.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Thank you for the input, but this switch will be toggled during normal operation. Our firmware needs to detect state changes on the switch in real time (or at least, fast enough where there isn't a noticeable delay for the user).